# How to create a dynamic array variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have these arrays and i want to loop through every array by creating a dynamic variable that put their name in foreach loop automatically something like this

```
foreach ($activities.$i as &$activity) { //$i = 1,2,3,4..
   //code

}

//activities
$activities1 = $_POST["activities1"];
$activities2 = $_POST["activities2"];
$activities3 = $_POST["activities3"];
$activities4 = $_POST["activities4"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier method is to simply use the array naming hack:

```
<input name="activities[1]" ..>
<input name="activities[2]" ..>
<input name="activities[3]" ..>
```

which makes `$_POST['activities']` you array:

```
foreach($_POST['activities'] as $i => $value) {
   // $i -> 1,2,3,4
}
```

But if you insist on embedding the index inside the key's name, then:

```
foreach(range(1,4) as $i) {
    foreach($_POST["activities{$i}"] as $value) {
        ...
    }
}
```